# JQuery : limit the scope of drag and drop elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frontend

I am using UIKit sortable plugin for drag and drop function of Html elements. I got 2 groups of elements which can be dragged and dropped in one html document. One group is draggable cards, each of which has a button to toggle the visibility of its modal and another group is draggable images insides the modal for each card.

I did it in the JQuery way "document on moved" to detect the drag and drop event of the group of cards but its scope conflict with that of draggable image in modals.

I guess the problem is in the JS code. How to control the scope of these 2 group of items so that they don't conflict with each other?
Thanks!

The following is my frontend code.

This is the JS code which controls the scope of draggable items

```
$(document).on('moved', '.uk-sortable', function(e) {
...
}
```

**I know I can code if condition inside the document on moved to split the control of drag and drop event of the 2 groups of elements but this approach is not so elegant. I would like to avoid this if possible.**

I have tried the id or class selector of the ul element enclosing the draggable items instead of 'document'. The callback function of the on moved event was only called when 'document' was in $().

BTW, the Html structure of cards is like this. (Symbols like {{}} are just part of the template of Laravel Blade file but this problem is not directly relevant to Laravel)

```
<ul id="ul-pj" class="uk-grid-small uk-child-width-1-2 
  uk-child-width-1-4@s" uk-sortable="handle: .uk-card" uk-grid>
@foreach ($projects as $item)
    <li id="li-{{ $item->id }}">
        <div class="uk-card card border-s4d" id="pj_card-{{ $item->id }}">
               ...
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

The Html structure of draggable images insides modal for each card

```
<div class="modal modal-lg fade" id="staff_order_modal-{{ $item->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staff_order_modal_label-{{ $item->id }}" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="staff_order_modal_label-{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul id="staff_order_ul-{{ $item->id }}" class="uk-grid-small uk-child-width-1-6 uk-child-width-1-6@s" uk-sortable="handle: .uk-sortable-staff" uk-grid>
                @foreach($item->staff as $staff_item)
                <li id="staff_order_li-{{ $staff_item->id }}">
                    @if (!empty($staff_item->photo_label))
                        <img id="pj_{{ $item->id }}_modal_staff-{{ $staff_item->id }}" class="rounded ctr-img uk-card uk-card-default uk-sortable-staff" style=" max-width:3.2em;max-height:3.2em;" src="{{ asset(config('img.avatar_staff'). $staff_item->photo_label) }}" alt="{{ $staff_item->name }}" />
                    @else
                        <img id="pj_{{ $item->id }}_modal_staff-{{ $staff_item->id }}" class="rounded ctr-img uk-card uk-card-default uk-sortable-staff" style="max-width:3.2em;max-height:3.2em;" src="{{ URL::asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="{{ $staff_item->name }}" />
                    @endif
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pj-staff-save" id="pj_staff_save-{{ $item->id }}">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the JS document of the UIKit sortable plugin but I am not sure how to control the scope of draggable elements.
https://getuikit.com/docs/sortable#javascript